# site not working on apple devices

Tags: php, iphone, ajax, ipad, ios7

I have recently worked on a small project. it's working fine on windows,android & other phones. but not working correctly with apple devices(iphone ipad). i have tested it on iphone4s,5 & ipad (os7). 
below are the few issues:

1. some times images not loading(i have used php to view images).
2. return back to home page link not working i m using java script on anchor tag().
3. problem with login system(javascript function fired on click it shows security popup) some times it doesn't load security box or if it loads, unable to verify code.

find Screen Shots here http://blackspidercreations.com/apple/screen.docx

so but the mistake that i have did, i have tested site on many apple simulators like browerstack ipadpreview etc. they all workin fine. please help me.

Link to project: blackspidercreations.com/cs

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please embed screenshots or provide direct link to images. A tech-savvy person would never open a random docx from the Internet.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Harry can't embed screenshots until he gets enough rep.  But it would be smart of him to create .jpg or .png files and edit his question to show, instead of having to rely on us to download on a potentially malicious docx file.

Comment: http://blackspidercreations.com/apple/1.JPG,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg,5.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Though I cannot answer points 2 or 3 without seeing the code, I had similar image problems once when developing for the iPhone. Make sure that the images are an appropriate size for the display. If the images are too large, the iPhone will not display them at all.

Comment: <?php
session_start();

if(isset($_REQUEST['image']) && isset($_REQUEST['token']) && !empty($_REQUEST['token']))
{
if(!isset($_SESSION['token'][$_REQUEST['token']]))
{
 return('Image Not found!');
}
$image = $_SESSION['token'][$_REQUEST['token']]; 
$path = 'resource/uploads/'.$image.'.pic';
unset($_SESSION['token'][$_REQUEST['token']]);
header("Content-type: ");

header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
                readfile($path);
    
return;

}

?>

Answer (score 0):

Hard to take a guess at the images issue without seeing the code.

Apple mobile devices don't actually a fire a click event when you interact with the web page. So if you are using jquery to do .click events, that is why it's not working. There is a relatively easy work around though, switch all your .click events to the following.

```
$(document).on("click touchstart", "#thing", function() { });
```